# Angular Universal issue afteer migrating from Angular v10 to v10.1

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have upgraded my project from v10 to v10.1
So after running an universal prerender I've getting this error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts:99:42 - error TS2344: Type 'P' does not satisfy the constraint 'Params'.
  Type 'P' is not assignable to type 'ParamsArray'.

99         extends core.ErrorRequestHandler<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery> { }
                                            ~
node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts:108:124 - error TS2344: Type 'P' does not satisfy the constraint 'Params'.
  Type 'P' is not assignable to type 'ParamsArray'.

108     interface Request<P = core.ParamsDictionary, ResBody = any, ReqBody = any, ReqQuery = core.Query> extends core.Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery> { }
                                                                                                                               ~
node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts:109:138 - error TS2344: Type 'P' does not satisfy the constraint 'Params'.
  Type 'P' is not assignable to type 'ParamsArray'.

109     interface RequestHandler<P = core.ParamsDictionary, ResBody = any, ReqBody = any, ReqQuery = core.Query> extends core.RequestHandler<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery> { }
```

Any ideas why?

Here is `git diff package json`

```
   "dependencies": {
-    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.4",
-    "@angular/cdk": "~10.0.2",
-    "@angular/common": "~10.0.4",
-    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.4",
-    "@angular/core": "~10.0.4",
+    "@angular/animations": "~10.1.2",
+    "@angular/cdk": "~10.2.1",
+    "@angular/common": "~10.1.2",
+    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.2",
+    "@angular/core": "~10.1.2",
     "@angular/flex-layout": "10.0.0-beta.32",
-    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.4",
-    "@angular/material": "~10.0.2",
-    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.4",
-    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.4",
-    "@angular/platform-server": "~10.0.4",
-    "@angular/router": "~10.0.4",
+    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.2",
+    "@angular/material": "~10.2.1",
+    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.2",
+    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.2",
+    "@angular/platform-server": "~10.1.2",
+    "@angular/router": "~10.1.2",
     "@ng-toolkit/universal": "^8.1.0",
-    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^10.0.1",
-    "@types/stripe-v3": "^3.1.19",
+    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^10.1.0",
+    "@types/stripe-v3": "^3.1.20",
     "express": "^4.15.2",
-    "ngx-cookie": "^4.1.2",
+    "ngx-cookie": "^5.0.0",
     "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.0",
-    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
-    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
-    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
+    "rxjs": "~6.6.3",
+    "tslib": "^2.0.1",
+    "zone.js": "~0.11.1"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
-    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.3",
-    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.1000.3",
-    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.3",
-    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.4",
-    "@nguniversal/builders": "^10.0.1",
-    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
-    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
+    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1001.2",
+    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.1001.2",
+    "@angular/cli": "~10.1.2",
+    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.2",
+    "@nguniversal/builders": "^10.1.0",
+    "@types/express": "^4.17.8",
+    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.14",
     "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
-    "@types/node": "^14.0.23",
+    "@types/node": "^14.10.3",
     "codelyzer": "^6.0.0-next.1",
-    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
+    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
     "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
-    "karma": "~5.1.0",
+    "karma": "~5.2.2",
     "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
     "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
-    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
+    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
     "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
-    "ng-packagr": "^10.0.2",
+    "ng-packagr": "^10.1.0",
     "protractor": "~7.0.0",
-    "ts-node": "~8.10.2",
-    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
-    "typescript": "~3.9.7"
+    "ts-node": "~9.0.0",
+    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
+    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
   }
 }
```

and here is `ng v` output

```
Angular CLI: 10.1.2
Node: 12.13.1
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 10.1.2
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1001.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.1001.2
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.1001.2
@angular-devkit/core               10.1.2
@angular-devkit/schematics         10.1.2
@angular/cdk                       10.2.1
@angular/flex-layout               10.0.0-beta.32
@angular/material                  10.2.1
@nguniversal/builders              10.1.0
@nguniversal/express-engine        10.1.0
@schematics/angular                8.3.28
@schematics/update                 0.1001.2
ng-packagr                         10.1.0
rxjs                               6.6.3
typescript                         4.0.2
```

UPDATE:
just run `yarn add express and @types/express` that install express": "^4.17.1 and "@types/express": "^4.17.8" but it won't help, getting the same error.

Comment: Can you try to replace `"express": "^4.15.2"`, with `"express": "~4.15.2",` and the same with the types.

Comment: @StPaulis just run `yarn add express and @types/express` that install `express": "^4.17.1` and `"@types/express": "^4.17.8"` but it won't help getting the same error

Comment: also was trying to downgrade to typescript@3.9.7 but same error so upgraded it back to v4

Comment: That's the reason I told you to replace to `~4.15.2` both in express and types,

Comment: Maybe something brokes in 17

Comment: @StPaulis got this error now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63948532/angular-universal-error-notyetimplemented